# how to Subtract 2 Columns in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

If given the table:

```
games_played(ID,home_team,away_team,homescore,awayscore)
```

inputs:

('1', 'USA', 'CAN', '0','2')

('2', 'USA', 'CAN', '1','2')

('3', 'USA', 'CAN', '3','0')

('4', 'SWE', 'CAN', '3','2')

('5', 'CAN', 'RUS', '3','2')

('6', 'DE', 'RUS', '0','2')

Output should be the teams: SWE, CAN

What would I do to find team with more home wins than losses?  I've tried doing this:

```
select home_team, count(*)
  from games_played
  where homescore > awayscore
  group by home_team
```

-

```
select home_team, count(*)
  from games_played
  where awayscore > homescore
  group by home_team
```

The first query should return the team name and the number of games they won at home.  The second should be the number of games they lost at home. This query doesn't work and I'm looking for another way. I know that I cant use count in 'where'

Comment: Alright, I've edited with input and outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT home_team,
COUNT(CASE WHEN homescore > awayscore THEN 1 END) AS gamesWon,
COUNT(CASE WHEN awayscore > homescore THEN 1 END) AS gamesLost
FROM games_played
GROUP BY home_team
```

**Result**:

[image]

---

Now to further return only teams where `gamesWon > gamesLost` you put it into a [common table expression](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html):

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT home_team,
COUNT(CASE WHEN homescore > awayscore THEN 1 END) AS gamesWon,
COUNT(CASE WHEN awayscore > homescore THEN 1 END) AS gamesLost
FROM games_played
GROUP BY home_team)

SELECT * FROM cte
WHERE gamesWon > gamesLost
```

**Result**:

[image]

---

**Repro**:

[[DEMO HERE]](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/6d7e1/1/1)

```
CREATE TABLE games_played (ID INT,home_team VARCHAR(20),away_team VARCHAR(20),homescore INT,awayscore INT);

/* Create few records in this table */
INSERT INTO games_played VALUES(1,'USA','CAN',0,2);
INSERT INTO games_played VALUES(2,'USA','CAN',1,2);
INSERT INTO games_played VALUES(3,'USA','CAN',3,0);
INSERT INTO games_played VALUES(4,'SWE','CAN',3,2);
INSERT INTO games_played VALUES(5,'CAN','RUS',3,2);
INSERT INTO games_played VALUES(6,'DE','RUS',0,2);


/* Verify */
-- SELECT * FROM games_played;

WITH cte AS (
SELECT home_team,
COUNT(CASE WHEN homescore > awayscore THEN 1 END) AS gamesWon,
COUNT(CASE WHEN awayscore > homescore THEN 1 END) AS gamesLost
FROM games_played
GROUP BY home_team)

SELECT * FROM cte
WHERE gamesWon > gamesLost
```

Comment: How would I further use that to isolate the countries CAN and SWE since those are the only 2 with more home wins than losses? Instead of outputting count of all home wins vs losses. I think I would need to create view of that and output when home_win > home_loss? Is there a way to do without using create view

Comment: @s878 yes, please see my final edits with explanation and demonstration.

Answer (score -1):

This is a simpler approach,

```
SELECT g.home_team AS Team
FROM games_played g
LEFT JOIN games_played Win ON Win.id = g.id AND Win.homescore > Win.awayscore
LEFT JOIN games_played Lost ON Lost.id = g.id AND Lost.homescore < Lost.awayscore
GROUP BY g.home_team
HAVING
COUNT(Win.home_team) > COUNT(Lost.home_team)
```

Comment: wouldn't this only output correct answer for this scenario, but if there was an instance where for example we had (1,'USA','CAN',3,2) then it wouldn't work since USA would have lost 1 home game but the count of games homes game won will be more than loss and it should be outputted.